# Suppose our ring $R = k[t]$. Let $M$ be the $R$-module $R[x]/(tx - t)$. Prove that $M$ isn't flat.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, flatness

I proved this problem before by the following theorem. Over PID 
Flat iff torsion free. Then, from this fact, we know that M isn't flat as it has torsion element. In the problem we were given hint that to consider the following sequence $0 \rightarrow (t) \rightarrow R$. I am guessing, we then proceed to show that $M \otimes_R (t)$ doesn't inject into $M \otimes_R R$. I couldn't show that this doesn't inject. If someone could help that would be nice.

Comment: what is $(t)$ ?

Comment: ideal generated by (t)

Comment: Found duplicate by searching "tx-t flat". Try it next time :)

Comment: @rschwieb I tried searching this first before posting but I probably can't search properly haha thanks :)